# JS e HTML - Publicação de Quotas

Tags: javascript

Criei um código de javascript onde mostra-me vários textos random, mas estes só mudam com o refresh da página.

E eu queria que mudassem a cada 5seg sem fazer refresh.

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  var quotes = [
    {
      text: " HEY ITS ME",
    },                    
    {
      text: " HEY YOU TO",
    }          

  ];
  var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> ' + quote.text + '';
})();
```

Comment: Porquê um array de objetos e não um array de `strings` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementById("quote");
var quotes = [
  {
   text: " HEY ITS ME",
  },                    
  {
   text: " HEY YOU TO",
  }          
];

function random() {
   var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
   div.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> ' + quote.text +'';
}

setInterval(random, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O que vc precisa é de interval. Esse tutorial vai te ajudar: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
setInterval(function(){
  // sua função
}, 3000); // a cada 3 segundos`
```

Comment: Dê uma descrição mais detalhada usando o exemplo da pergunta, ou mova para os comentários